# Update all packages except one

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

is there any way to update all packages except one?
For instance when I created new project I need to update all packages except jQuery. It should stay at same version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could write a custom script for updating the packages like the following and execute it in the package manager console

```
  $list = Get-package -project {Add project name here}
  for($i=0; $i -lt $list.Length;$i ++ ) { if($list[$i].Id -ne "jquery") { Update-Package -project {Add project name here} $list[$i].Id } }
```

Comment: You should first run an update-package -whatif and read through the output to make sure that none of the new updates want a later version of jQuery. If they do not require a later version, the solution here is most ideal. If a newer version is required by one of the updates, you will have to update the package that requires the later version with the -IgnoreDependencies flag and cross your fingers

Answer (score -2):

no there is no direct way of doing that. May be you can update all, then uninstall JQuery and install the version of jquery you want.