# Manage Nuget for solution tells me to update package but provides no projects to update

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, portable-class-library, mr.gestures

When I click `Manage Nuget for Solution` on my `Solution` I check for updates and see that one of my Packages `Mr.Gestures` (although I'm not sure the package matters) needs updating.

I click `Update` and it asks me to `Select Projects` but provides me with no projects to select as they are all disabled (see screenshot below).

[image]

What do I need to do so that my `solution` recognizes the `Package` it is up to date?

Comment: give it a try from in built nuget power shell command line , nuget update command would take you some solution here ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found how to solve this problem:

1. Go to your solution folder
2. Go to the /packages folder
3. Delete the pacakge folder that is outdated (In my case Mr.Gestures 1.2.1)
4. Reload Nuget for solution and the package will have disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try from in built nuget power shell command line , nuget update command would take you some solution here .. take a look at [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249356/update-all-packages-except-one/31276284#31276284)

**From link:**

> You could write a custom script for updating the packages like the following and execute it in the package manager console

```
  $list = Get-package -project {Add project name here}
  for($i=0; $i -lt $list.Length;$i ++ ) { if($list[$i].Id -ne "jquery") { Update-Package -project {Add project name here}
```

Comment: So the results from this are that `Get-Package` returns `Mr.Gesutes 1.2.1` installed and `1.2.2`. but doing `Get-Package` on each individual project none report any reference to `Mr.Gestures 1.2.1`